How to emit one particle after another in ParticleSystem Emitter
I want to emit only 1 image at time, and every after emit i want next to be the second one.
I cant find any solution to this one.
Maybe I should use some timer, but Im not sure where.
Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ParticleSystem {
            id: xy
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            Age {
                system: notes
                anchors.fill: parent
                once: true
                lifeLeft: 1000
                advancePosition: false
            }
            ImageParticle {
                groups: ["x"]
                source: "images/x.png"

            }
            ImageParticle {
                groups: ["y"]
                source: "images/y.png"
            }

            Emitter {
                group: "y"
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                velocity: AngleDirection {
                    angle: 270
                    angleVariation: 35
                    magnitude: 20
                }
                lifeSpan: 5000
                emitRate: 2
                size: 8
                endSize: 15

            }
            Emitter {
                group: "x"
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                velocity: AngleDirection {
                    angle: 270
                    angleVariation: 35
                    magnitude: 20
                }
                lifeSpan: 5000
                emitRate: 2
                size: 6
                endSize: 13
            }
        }

            Age {
                system: xy
                anchors.fill: parent
                once: true
                lifeLeft: 1000
                advancePosition: false
            }
        }
}

Thanks in advance for your answers.
Docs:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-particles-particlesystem.html#particleStates-prop
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-particles-emitter.html


Because you want fine-grain control of when your Emitters fire, I recommend turning off automatic emitters, by setting emitRate: 0 then, you call alternate calls to the respective Emitter.burst() methods. In the following example, I use a Timer to schedule such calls:
    Timer {
        property int c: 0
        interval: 300
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: [emx, emy][++c % 2].burst(1)
    }
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ParticleSystem {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            ImageParticle { groups: ["x"]; source: "images/x.svg" }
            ImageParticle { groups: ["y"]; source: "images/y.svg" }
            Emitter {
                id: emx
                group: "x"
                velocity: AngleDirection { angle: 270; angleVariation: 35; magnitude: 100 }
                emitRate: 0; lifeSpan: 1000; size: 8; endSize: 31
            }
            Emitter {
                id: emy
                group: "y"
                velocity: AngleDirection { angle: 270; angleVariation: 35; magnitude: 100 }
                emitRate: 0; lifeSpan: 1000; size: 8; endSize: 31
            }
        }
    }

You can Try it Online!
